# java.lang.ClassCastException: batch.commons.BatchFacadeImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider

Tags: java

When I try to make a request for soap WS, I receive the following error

```
public void lanzarTrabajo() {
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");

        SrvTrabajoFachadaV7Service srvTrabajoFachadaV7Service = new SrvTrabajoFachadaV7Service();
        BatchFacade batchFacade = new BatchFacadeImpl(srvTrabajoFachadaV7Service);
        Map<String, String> params = getParamsMock();

        Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)batchFacade).getRequestContext();
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("user:password".getBytes())));
        req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

        long idTrabajo = batchFacade.iniciarTrabajo("PRECARTERA", params);
    }
```

This is te error exit.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aviva.batch.commons.BatchFacadeImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but I would suggest that depending on the client generator you may or may not cast your `qport`.

For instance,

- If you generated your WSDL interface with  **JAX-WS** (by `wsimport`), you can cast `((javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider) batchFacade)`
- If you generated your WSDL interface with **JAX-RPC** clients (created by `clientgen`) 
  you can cast `((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) batchFacade)`

I don't know how you generated your interface, but you may try the other cast in your case:

```
javax.xml.rpc.Stub stub = (javax.xml.rpc.Stub) batchFacade;
stub._setProperty("Key","Value");
```